# How to display full URL in address tab of Dreamweaver CS5?

Tags: adobe, dreamweaver, ip-address, flash-cs5

In the address bar of the browser navigation tab, it shows the absolute path of the file, but it is so long that it gets truncated and I can't read the exact file that I'm working on!  Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I got it... just hover your mouse over the truncated field for a couple seconds and a tooltip will pop up with the full address.  I was just frantically clicking on it like an impatient moron and it was canceling the scheduled tooltip display.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a "browser navigation tab" is. In Dreamweaver CS5 on Windows, the full url is displayed in the title bar of the document. When documents are maximized a tab will display the file name, and the full file url will display in the title bar on the right hand side. This full url gets truncated when there are too many documents open. The truncation is done from the left so you may lose some of the folders, but you should still see the file name. If this is the case, then a quick solution is to close some documents. Or Perhaps don't nest your files so deeply, or don't have really long file/folder names.

Another option is an extension that I wrote a while ago called Document Path Toolbar: http://communitymx.com/abstract.cfm?cid=A01CEAEA3CA40B36 The extension adds a toolbar that has a text field that displays the full url to the local file. It has an option that allows you to updated the width of the text field if you have longer file paths (I think that such modifications requires a restart of Dreamweaver). It is commercial but not much. As I no longer contribute to CommunityMX, I won't receive anything for a purchase should you decide it is something that you could benefit from.